# PHP form not inserting data into database when executed

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to PHP and I am trying to just make a little form that inserts a name, email and ID into a table in my database but it is not working
index.php:

```
    <form action="getData.php" method="post">
      Name
      <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="40" value="<?=$name;?>" />
      Email
      <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" value="<?=$email;?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

getData.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit"){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tj_testdb";
$password = "tjtorin04";
$dbname = "tj_testdb";

$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
  echo "Connections failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO data(id,name,email) VALUES(0,$name,$email)";

  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "inserted data";
  }
  else{
    echo "failed";
  }

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get some error?

Comment: it is echoing failed like I put in the code

Comment: echo the resulting $sql - echo $sql; and look at it. If it looks good, grab it and paste it into phpmyadmin ( if you use that ) as an SQL statement and see what that gives you. Then come back with the error it reports :)

Answer (score -1):

If your ids auto-increase, you don’t need to put it in your SQL line, also the variable (name and email) in your HTML code aren’t defined